# Convert unknown size vector<vector<string>> into a char

Tags: c++, vector, char

Need to Convert unknown size vector into a char in a way to manipulate each char individually.

```
void encode(vector<vector<string>>& data,int encode_level,string filename)
```

attempted to try

```
vector<vector<char>> char_data(data.begin(), data.end());
```

but it is throwing error code C2664

Comment: what are you trying to do? please post a valid case

Comment: You already can manipulate each character individually, `string` provides a subscript operator. Why aren't you just using that?

Comment: thank you, I am fairly new to coding and didn't know about subscript operators

Answer (score 0):

I've made a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184337/convert-unknown-size-vectorvectorstring-into-a-char#comment69568717_41184337) but it seems as though [`string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) is the tool for this question.

Incidentally [`string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) also provides this functionality, but does runtime checking to ensure that the element is in bounds.

So for example to access an individual character you could do:

```
data[1][2][3]
```